# How to responsively use margin and padding with bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive

Lately I've been working on a project with bootstrap in order to make it responsive for all devices. I've experienced some issues when i use a padding or a margin. It looks good for most of the screens, but I still experience some problems with it.

I was wondering if there is a way to use those padding and margin without writing @media queries for all screens that I have issues?

I've read some articles about using less files, but its kinda confusing.

I appreciate the help. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting padding as a percentage value. The padding of each element will thus be relative to its size as it appears on the screen. [Here's](https://teamtreehouse.com/community/padding-percentage-relative-to-its-elements-width) a good description of this.

Comment: I'm using percentage for the values but still i have some issues. Thank you for the article tho!